# Is it better for readability for links where link text equals document title to both be in title case, or both be in the usual capitalization?

Tags: usability, readability, letter-case

To pick one example of a class of links I'm considering changing, https://CJSHayward.com/library/ has a link text of "Ajax Without JavaScript or Client-Side Scripting". The link points to https://CJSHayward.com/ajax/, with a title of "Ajax Without JavaScript or Client-Side Scripting".

What should I weigh in considering between the two options below:

Ajax **W**ithout JavaScript or **C**lient-**S**ide **S**cripting
Ajax **w**ithout JavaScript or **c**lient-**s**ide **s**cripting

Which is better from a usability perspective? Is the UX perspective any different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was one consideration I realized that is, to me, an overriding consideration that stopped me from an already started project of learning link titles.

It is common practice for link text to be the title of the link target. It is, arguably, even more common practice for link text to effectively be some improvised comment or remark about the link target.

The following link capitalization, in terms of "non-verbal communication", is ambiguous as to whether the link text identifies the target's title, or whatever remark or summary the author improvised; it seems to lend itself to reading the link text as an improvised remark written to match the context of the page it appears on:

> Xxx x xxxxx [**x**xx x xx **x**xxxxx **x**xxxxxxx](https://CJSHayward.com) xxxx xxxxxx x x.

The title case capitalization strips out the ambiguity in the case of repeating a document title, which can be particularly helpful if the document's title does not fit the flow of the sentence to the degree one would often encounter with an "improvised remark" link text:

> Xxx x xxxxx [**X**xx x xx **X**xxxxx **X**xxxxxxx](https://CJSHayward.com) xxxx xxxxxx x x.

That is why, after doing significant work to start converting all the text of [CJSHayward.com](https://CJSHayward.com) from title case to sentence case, I am rolling the transaction back.

Answer (score 1):

For content within your control, use sentence case consistently except for proper nouns. The reasons for this are:

- Not all of the content you link to will follow the same style rules, so be consistent with the content you control.
- Links are not always worded exactly as the target content, so there is no need for them to follow the exact formatting
- Titles and links should be clearly differentiated from other content, but this is already done through different visual styling: there is no need to use a different type of capitailisation as well
- Where other people are writing content, not everyone understands how to use title case appropriately - some will capitalise properly, others will capitalise words such as Of or And. This introduces inconsistencies into your design.
- People using screen magnifiers will often focus on a small part of the screen. Sentence case makes it clearer where the start of a sentence is, compared to title case.
- When writing copy, sentence case lets you use puns and other wordplay because only proper nouns are capitalised.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the exact phrase from the destination page, then it should display the same capitalization style as being used there.

However if you are explaining the content that this link contains, then you can use your own page's capitalization style.